# Visual Studio 2013 Run Settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am building an MVC application using VS 2013 and when I have edited a view (which I will eventually turn into a partial view) and want to run the whole application, Visual studio directs me to that view as a page. As the controller for the view takes a parameter to get the correct model out of a database, this results in an error. Is there a setting to just have VS run the main page of the web application no matter what the last edited file was?

Comment: Welcome to SO, to make it easier to help you what kind of error do you get? Also if you show some reproducible or at least relevant part of your code it would be better.

Comment: This is not really about the code, it's about changing a setting. The mention of an error was more to give background as to why I want to change the setting. Essentially the error is that I forgot to pass a non-nullable parameter to the controller (and that particular parameter should be non-nullable), VS just opens it without regards to context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open your project properties, and select "Web". Here you can define the page you want to load.

[image]

Comment: You will also need to pass in the parameter value as part of the **Specific Page** setting.  In the above example, if you wanted to call the HomeController Index ActionMethod which has a required **id** parameter you would enter the following into the **Specific Page** field: /Home/Index?id=123 or if you had routing setup for the **id** parameter value: /Home/Index/123

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your routing in the Global.asax.cs file ?

there you can declare which page to start the application on

This link may help *

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs